# How to alter the URL in a link with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code, but it is not working the way I thought.

```js
var myList = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var url = "http://www.site2.com";

for (i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
  url = url + myList[i];
  alert("the new link is " + url);
  myList[i].setAttribute('href', url);
}
```

```html
<a href="/link1.html">link1</a>
<a href="/link2.html">link2</a>
<a href="/link3.html">link3</a>
<a href="/link4.html">link4</a>
<a href="/link5.html">link5</a>
```

How to get this result:

```
<a href="http://www.site2.com/link1.html">link1</a>
<a href="http://www.site2.com/link2.html">link2</a>
<a href="http://www.site2.com/link3.html">link3</a>
<a href="http://www.site2.com/link4.html">link4</a>
<a href="http://www.site2.com/link5.html">link5</a>
```

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: @LemuelBotha I just noticed that I was adding stuff to `url` over and over... hahahaha... But I appreciate your time! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the current attribute value and then append with the `url` string while setting attribute.

```js
var myList = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var url = "http://www.site2.com";

for (i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
  myList[i].setAttribute('href', url + myList[i].getAttribute('href'));
  //-----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----
}
```

```html
<a href="/link1.html">link1</a>
<a href="/link2.html">link2</a>
<a href="/link3.html">link3</a>
<a href="/link4.html">link4</a>
<a href="/link5.html">link5</a>
```

Comment: @PauloDosSantos : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

get href attribute of anchor and add to url

```
var myList = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var url = "http://www.site2.com";

for (i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
  myurl = url + myList[i].getAttribute('href');
  //alert("the new link is " + url);
  myList[i].setAttribute('href', myurl);
}
```

here is working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/wrycuoma/